# Number of "User was removed" increasing rapidly

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-users

I know what "User was removed" means clearly. But for some days I am seeing this message very often. Around 6 times in a week. Does that mean that I have something to do?

Comment: Means a lot of users that voted on your posts are getting removed off the site, either by a self removal or a mod kicking them off

Comment: @WhatsThePoint thanks for the reply. But as I already stated in the question, I know what it means. What bugs me is the abnormal increase in the number.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The moderators have been a bit busy cleaning up a largish sock network, where the master account tried to make their socks look 'normal' by voting more widely. This has resulted in a number of user vote invalidation events for people. None of these accounts were connected to you, you were just another vote target for the socks.

There may be one or two more such events as we root out any remainder, but it's mostly done now.

Comment: Please tell me you banned the master.

Comment: You must have some pretty powerful tools to be able to track down that sort of thing!

Comment: Is _"you were just another vote target for the socks"_ possibly related to the predominance of [tag:android] posts from Anees?

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. But it would be nice if users were able to know which post they lost reputation from.

Comment: @Anees you can't know for which post you lost reputation and which user was removed. You may bring it as a feature request but it's rarest case and I think the devs don't like to implement such a feature

Comment: I lost 20 rep on ips.se. Why are you breaking the border and removing users from ips.se? ~O_O~

Comment: @SagarV What makes you think it is related? And if it's related, it seems normal to remove the sock puppet accounts from all sites, doesn't it? Moreover Martijn didn't mention whether this is limited to SO or not.

Comment: @Joshua: a lengthy suspension was involved, yes.

Comment: @Anees: sorry, that's not something that can be disclosed as that would make it easier to identify how an individual voted. Votes are anonymous, and not even clearing fraudulent votes should expose that information.

Comment: @SagarV: users are removed from sites all the time; the specific sock network I am referring to was limited to Stack Overflow however, so any 'User was removed' entries elsewhere were not related.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok. I thought you people discussed it with other site mods and everyone is doing this.

Comment: What exactly is meant by 'sock account' ? Is someone having fun voting aimlessly ?

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet)

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan in a nutshell, a second(if not more) account(s) to upvote posts on your main account so you get free internet points

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: any additional account that is used to circumvent system limitations and trying to appear independent from the account that controls it would be a sock puppet. That's not just limited to upvoting your own posts.

Comment: I know that rep is earned fairly on SO - Gaining numbers like your self or other on this site you cant just buy it. I also know that SO i mostly community driven and very few people actually have a salary from SO. But there are groups on the onion web that offer all sorts of services, which include all sorts of social media boosting. Krebs on security scratches the surface of these rackets. Again I am happy with the changes and extremely grateful to the excellent moderators. It really makes a big difference with the new changes. Thanks

Comment: @Anees if you want it badly enough make a bot that tracks the score on all of your posts. Inexplicable changes must be user was removed.

Comment: Why is the user removal continuing to increase? I have had 40 points vanish in the past two days. SO and Meta need to stop the willy-nilly removal of users who have cast significant votes. There is no reason to "Undo" votes when removing a user, just remove the user.