# When someone have his answer accepted, and then the user is removed

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that sometimes when answering some questions, I have got several upvotes and acceptance by the question asker.

After a few days my reputation points were reduced and I got notified **User was removed**.

If someone is asking a good question, and people found it helpful for them and upvoted the question and answer as well then why are we removing such questions from the site? I believe if a user is removed then we should show the poster name as "anonymous" - but question should remain.

What should be there in your opinion? Question deletion, or question existence with "Anonymous"?

Comment: It's possible that these were questions from a voting ring. A voting ring has [recently been dismantled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373573/812149).

Comment: @S.L.Barth: this specific user wasn't affected by that.

Comment: You haven't lost any points due to removed posts, and only lost a few points from a user-removed event in July. Do you have a specific post in mind that I missed?

Answer (score 4):

There is already such a system in place, albeit only since a few months ago. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312594/167646:

> So after reviewing the data, here's what I think makes sense: delete a user's posts along with them only when those posts...
>
> - ...score < 0 AND
> - ...are closed OR
> - ...have no answers scoring > 0
>
> This change is now live.

Comment: that question was having nearly 5 upvotes, 3 answers and 1 accepted one.

Comment: Can you link the question?

Comment: Question has been removed along with User and now there is no linkup with that.

Comment: Then how are you sure there is actually a question removed? According to Martijn there's no such recent event. You likely simply lost reputation from votes by a now removed user.

Comment: I got a notification "User was Removed" and lost certain rep points, when I opened my all answer list I was not able to find that question on which I got those rep points.

Comment: Possibly the answer you are looking for was removed for an unrelated reason, and the reputation you lost was for a different answer.

Comment: @DeepPatel: votes cast by a user account that is now deleted are *gone*, you won't be able to find the answer or questions that lost votes now, as their scores have long since been adjusted.

Comment: @DeepPatel are you sure the entire questions were removed. "User was removed" usually means someone who upvoted or downvoted one of your posts no longer has an account, not that the whole Q&A is gone.