# Does Stack Overflow prevent cartels?

Tags: discussion, reputation, security, voting-fraud

Let's say I organize a group of users (or fake users/bots) with malicious intent to inflate reputation. They will ask questions and upvote each others' answers. To keep things safe, questions will look legit but very boring and overly specific to avoid the attention of the wider community and bounty hunters.

Does Stack Overflow platform have means of recognizing and banning such activity?

Disclaimer: I'm asking out of curiosity and don't have any intention to do anything like that.

Comment: In short: Yes, such activities are detected and the participating user accounts are banned or deleted.

Comment: This type of activity is called a voting ring, and is forbidden by the terms of use and the rules of the platform. There are a few different ways they are found out, and they usually don't last long.

Comment: @Magisch thanks for terminology highlight. I can see now there are many duplicate questions out there

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322114/voting-rings-how-to-handle-organized-groups-upvoting-each-other and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373651/what-is-the-purpose-of-voting-rings/373670#373670

Comment: But *why would you want to do that?* I mean ... you get reputation, nothing else.

Comment: @JonasWilms: I believe the quote goes: _"With great rep comes great power"_. Rep unlocks some features, but they never get enough this way, any way.

Comment: @JonasWilms fake internet points can be very coveted by some in and of themselves, but there are also plenty of cases of real-world effects where folks judge merit or skill based off of SO rep. Joel Spolsky himself once boasted he'd be willing to hire anyone on the spot who had at least 10,000 rep on Stack Overflow (this was *years* ago, though, when there were way fewer people with that much rep on SO). But many people do put their SO profile on their CVs; more rep points *does* looks better than fewer rep points, everything else being equal.

Comment: @JonasWilms some companies hunt candidates for intersting positions based on their SO reputation and github activity

Comment: Keep in mind it's hard to create good content questions that has not been asked before and is not not off topic. The way you describe it, in my ears it more sounds like you will get downvotes because of bad questions, and probably a few will downvote the answers too because the question is bad. Net sum, probably a slow gain. If you instead focus on just answering I think you can get more than 10x the rep point you get on your system.

Comment: @KoIA thats true, I already received Senior offerings based on my SO profile although I judt finished school ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they have kinda a script that runs at 3 AM UTC that checks for serial voting (voting up and down several times within short period by a particular user on other's post).

When detected, the reputation lost or gained is reverted back to normal with title **Serial Voting was reversed**.

And most probably the causing user will also receive a moderator message (when contacted by the affected user of when a custom moderator flag is provoked) or warning of not doing such activities further. If done repeatedly, the account can be banned too.

Comment: The 3:00 automatic vote reversal does not raise a mod flag iirc, so unless someone notices the fishy reversals and flags, no mods will get involved.

Comment: Ah, I know but the mods get information about such activities and also contact the particular user

Comment: As far as I know, they will not contact the user unless the behavior is manually reported by a user or they come across it directly in the scope of other investigations.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update the answer

Comment: The question is not about "serial voting" per se, but about "organized targeted voting", either by using bots or other users. Not saying that the same script doesn't catch the these things, but I do not believe it is exactly the same thing.

Comment: 03:00 UTC is the correct time indeed.