# Why was "How to find the sum of elements at compile time?" deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

The question ["How to find the sum of elements at compile time?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58005261/how-to-find-the-sum-of-elements-at-compile-time) received nineteen upvotes, zero downvotes, and five answers (where the answers had total of thirty-eight upvotes and no downvotes), and spawned [another interesting question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58005977/why-has-stdaccumulate-not-been-made-constexpr-in-c20).

. . . and then it was deleted by a diamond mod, and I can't tell why. Are we allowed to know why this was done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Moderators had been investigating a trail of abnormal activity where accounts were asking and answering each other's questions in a pattern that indicated intervention was necessary.

That doesn't automatically mean there's an absence of good faith, but mods don't want folks wasting time answering stuff with a good chance that it might need to be deleted for administrative reasons. When this comes up, mods need to examine depth and breadth of unusual activity individually, which can take some time.

I don't want to offer speculation publicly, but I can say the actions were justified even if if it's not quite apparent why. If this turns out to be totally benign (which can occasionally happen) the posts will be restored.

Comment: Is there a possibility it might be undeleted even if foul play is discovered? It appears that the question is legitimate and well recieved. Disassociation or account deletion might be a better solution for the posts on this particular question if long term action is needed.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes. The ToS requires contributions to belong to users that submit them. As long as that's totally in the clear. NB: We're not accusing anyone of anything, we just need to be sure a certain pattern is in fact benign.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I don't really understand this -- "asking and answering each other's questions" is what Stack Exchange is all about, and maybe I'm just hopelessly naive, but I can't picture what "a pattern that indicated intervention was necessary" might mean (is there a *non*-good-faith reason to ask interesting questions and answer them?) -- but I'll trust that y'all know what you're doing, and that this is as much of answer as we can get. :-)

Comment: @ruakh Most likely, Tim is talking about investigating a possible voting ring, sock puppet, or other kind of abuse to build up reputation.

Comment: @jpmc26: Does Stack Overflow reputation have some sort of practical benefit that I'm not aware of? I mean, the swag at 100k is lovely -- I wear the t-shirt a lot -- but it's really more of a "nice gesture of appreciation" than a "thing to orchestrate a voting ring in the hopes of getting". What am I missing?

Comment: @jpmc26: Never mind, I've belatedly Googled: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373651/what-is-the-purpose-of-voting-rings . It still seems strange, but I mostly get it now.

Comment: @ruakh depends on the employers you interact with.

Comment: @KevinB: Ah. I, on the other hand, can't imagine wanting to bring my employer's attention to just how much time I spend on this site. :-P

Comment: Still deleted. Investigation still ongoing?

Comment: @MarkAmery If it's still deleted, it's very likely that the moderators have a high certainty that the content was just copied from elsewhere (and they had no right to submit it in the first place).

Comment: @TimPost I am very curious about how the mods might've made that determination when there's no match on Google. Are you able to disclose anything?

Comment: @MarkAmery Paywalls are sometimes used (along with a permanent redirect) to avoid DMCA complaints and drop something from indexes. The mods are very certain that the context around the content getting posted is worth keeping it deleted, and they have the most information, so I'm going to defer to them. It's not something they take lightly (nobody wants good content removed). But the pattern surrounding it? Yeah, I support their choice.