# Why is my reputation reversed when there is not a previous sudden boost?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting-correction

Today I have checked my profile and the last entry under `Reputation` is:

> reversal -155 Voting corrected ([learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed))

I do not see any sudden boost in reputation, caused by someone euphorically voting my posts up, which should be reversed. My last 155 reputation points I have earned in the course of 3.5 months.

What is the reason for this reversal?

Comment: There can be other reasons, such as a user that has targetted your posts in the past, or perhaps there's been upvoting of posts by a voting ring (there was one such event earlier this year if I recall correctly). The [learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) link you omitted tells you more about why they are reversed.

Comment: _The learn more link you omitted tells you more about why they are reversed_ No it does not. I have read it many times in the past, including this time. The provided reason is: `Most commonly, when a single user continually votes (up or down) on many of your posts __within a short period of time__, the system considers these votes to be invalid and removes them.` Note: the emphasys is mine. As mentioned, I do not see any sudden (within a short period of time) boost in my rep. history.

Comment: Most commonly doesn't mean "this is always the case."

Comment: Other reasons are not explained.

Comment: The first line states: *"When votes are cast improperly, such as when someone misuses Stack Exchange systems, we remove those votes."* The votes were improper and so were removed; that's all that matters.

Comment: Then the question would be: which votes are considered improper? The only ones known to me are the targeted ones.

Comment: "within an extended period of time" is also a reason. It's just not automatically removed the next day because it's not as obvious. Targeted votes don't have to be within a short period.

Comment: *"which votes are considered improper?"* If you are asking which posts were affected, you aren't informed.

Comment: _If you are asking which posts were affected, you aren't informed._ I can't understand what do you mean by that.

Comment: Given the timing of the reversal event (not at 03:00/0:00 UTC) a Community Manager have reversed votes. That happens when the automatic systems don't catch the voting irregularity and manual checks and verifications are being done to cherry-pick which casted votes are to be invalidated. These investigations take ALL voting history into account and might impact multi users which in this case also involved votes cast on your posts. Voting is still private so even after this event no-one will come forward and reveal to you exactly *why*  this happened as that might compromise confidentiality

Comment: *"I can't understand what do you mean by that."* Then please explain what you mean by the comment you made if that isn't the answer.

Comment: @Larnu, you have cited: _Whan votes are case improperly_ The only improper usage of the voting system, explained in the link, is the ones, which target one person in a short time. Apparently, there are other missuses, which are not mentioned. Then the question is, which is also considered illegal.

Comment: @rene, if I understand correctly, your comment confirms that, what Henry Ecker said in his comment under the only one at the moment answer. Please check my following comment and tell me if I got that right. Thank you!

Comment: We've already covered a few here, @scopchanov. [What is the purpose of voting rings?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373651/what-is-the-purpose-of-voting-rings) and the linked question give some examples of other improper actions by users in rings.

Comment: As I have said, the post from [Henry Ecker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419532/why-is-my-reputation-reversed-when-there-is-not-a-previous-sudden-boost/419533?noredirect=1#comment920439_419533) with the post of [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419532/why-is-my-reputation-reversed-when-there-is-not-a-previous-sudden-boost/419533?noredirect=1#comment920440_419532) helped me clarify myself the issue. Thank you all for your time and effort!

Comment: “which votes are considered improper?” - You won’t be told this information. Important thing to understand, the votes were never legitimate, so it wasn’t a punishment against you.  Now if you were suspended for voting irregularities that’s a different story.

Comment: I have an app over on Glitch to audit your reputation events: https://se-reputation-audit.glitch.me/. The app does require authentication (as it needs access to your profile data) but all data-collection is done client-side, in your browser. It does have detail records for "vote_fraud_reversal" and once all events are processed (that might take some time as your browser needs to make several calls to the stack api) on the detail tab for "vote fraud reversal" you'll find links to the posts that had their votes reversed.

Comment: @rene, thank you for the link! My intent was not to find out which posts are affected though, but to understand why this has happened in the first place. With the kind help from Henry Ecker and from you now I know.

Comment: @SecurityHound, the important thing is to explain the way the site works to reduce the frustration from "nice" surprises like this one. The [learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) link does not provide enough information. At least the text there should be extended with [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419532/why-is-my-reputation-reversed-when-there-is-not-a-previous-sudden-boost?noredirect=1#comment920439_419533).

Comment: A note: you called it "my reputation". I like to think that we don't own reputation, we lease it. Stack Overflow giveth, Stack Overflow taketh away. Sanity on this site is to be able to see events such as this happen and accept it as-is. "Voting corrected" is enough explanation.

Comment: @Gimby The _the Lord gives and the Lord takes away_ approach might have worked in the dark ages. Sanity on this site (as well as everywhere else, where community is being build) means that the users are aware of the rules of the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419532/13552470#comment920440_419532) comment:

> Given the timing of the reversal event (not at 03:00/0:00 UTC) a Community Manager have reversed votes. That happens when the automatic systems don't catch the voting irregularity and manual checks and verifications are being done to cherry-pick which casted votes are to be invalidated. These investigations take ALL voting history into account and might impact multi users which in this case also involved votes cast on your posts. Voting is still private so even after this event no-one will come forward and reveal to you exactly why this happened as that might compromise confidentiality

From [Henry Ecker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15497888/henry-ecker) in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419532/why-is-my-reputation-reversed-when-there-is-not-a-previous-sudden-boost/419533?noredirect=1#comment920439_419533) comment:

> Voting rings sometimes sink their votes into random (or a specific set of) users to make their votes seem more legitimate/obfuscate who they are actually targeted upvoting. When all their votes are reversed this affects everyone they voted for, not just the individuals who were being intentionally targeted.

These two comments, as you have mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419532/why-is-my-reputation-reversed-when-there-is-not-a-previous-sudden-boost/419533?noredirect=1#comment920450_419533), displays some of the possible reasons to this phenomenon.

A little more food for thought: As you may already know, serial *downvoting* is a very common way to get "revenge" on other users here on the Stack Exchange community... by bringing their reputation points to a number lower than what it should be.

*However*, in some cases, a user might serial *upvote* another *(active)* user's posts to cause a much more negative impact (on their reputation points), and that is by upvoting the active user's posts in a way that will be detected *(and reversed)* in the future, but causing the targeted user to hit the reputation cap for that day. Repeat the process for many days, and that's hundreds of reputation points down the drain... ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I didn't even think about how evil the serial upvoting can be. I'm kind of uncomfortable with the todo steps being present in this answer :/

Comment: @Gimby I only thought of it because my account was a victim of it :)

Answer (score 9):

Presumably someone has been upvoting your posts slowly rather than all at once. Whether it's within a short period of time or slowly users are not allowed to target others when they vote.

Comment: Now that is something I could not understand. You tell me, that in the last 3.5 months I have received upvotes from only one person?

Comment: No, @scopchanov , they could have made all those votes years ago, and they have just been noticed after an investigation. You might have been the only person targeted by them. And, again, it might have not been an individual, but a voting ring.

Comment: Voting rings sometimes sink their votes into random (or a specific set of) users to make their votes seem more legitimate/obfuscate who they are actually targeted upvoting. When all their votes are reversed this affects everyone they voted for, not just the individuals who were being intentionally targeted.

Comment: @HenryEcker, let me check if I understand you correctly. There are two (or more) persons, who mainly upvote each others posts. This is a __voting ring__. Occasionally they vote for someone else. When they are caught, all they votings are reversed, including the occasional ones. Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes. That is the general idea of the situation I was describing. Rene echoed this same idea in [the comment here](/posts/comments/920440). Again, there's no way to know for sure why the votes were reversed and it's unlikely that information would ever be disclosed.

Comment: @HenryEcker, then I've understood you perfectly, including the confirmation from rene. For me personally, your comment explains the situation better than the answer given by Robert Lonson, with all my respect. If you like to post it as an answer, instead of as a comment, I would be glad to accept it.

Comment: @scopchanov My answer does not mention voting rings as I don't want to imply that you're in such a ring or have done anything wrong.

Comment: @RobertLongson, the way I understand it, is not that I am a accused to be a part of a voting ring(s), but fell a victim of such. They voted for my posts not because they found them useful, but to make their other upvotes seem legit. That is important information in my opinion.

Comment: As I have said, the post from [Henry Ecker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419532/why-is-my-reputation-reversed-when-there-is-not-a-previous-sudden-boost/419533?noredirect=1#comment920439_419533) with the post of [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419532/why-is-my-reputation-reversed-when-there-is-not-a-previous-sudden-boost/419533?noredirect=1#comment920440_419532) helped me clarify myself the issue. Thank you all for your time and effort!